# What do all the ways to express past events mean, and when is one better than the others?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, tenses, auxiliary-verbs, perfect-aspect

I’d like to clear convey that the documents were all *“sent on this day, the twenty-third of August”*, which is ***today*** as of this writing. When would you use each of these constructions?

1. I **sent** all the documents 23 August.
2. I **have sent** all the documents 23 August.
3. I **had sent** all the documents 23 August.

Or is there a better way to write it so that it reads more clearly and will be better understood?  What about:

4. I **did send** all the documents 23 August.

Answer (score 2):

> I **sent** all the documents *on* 23 August.

(that's when I did it; or on August 23, American style)

> I **have** (already) **sent** all the documents.

(this is a fact, a completed action, no date)

> I **had sent** all the documents on 23 August and I **received** a confirmation
>   yesterday.

(one action followed another one in the past)

> I **did send** all the documents on 23 August.

(it's true /or: actually, despite your doubt/, I confirm the following)